# What permission to see shared posts on my Facebook page feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-permissions

I have an app which I am admin and a page which I am also admin. I want to be able to read the feed from the app (which is a hosted web service).

I have created access tokens (page and user) with these permissions `read_insights, manage_pages, pages_show_list, public_profile` and I am calling this endpoint ...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{{pageId}}/feed?access_token={{longLivedPageAccessToken}}
```

I only get back posts that I have created, not posts that have been shared to my Page.

[Facebooks docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v6.0/page/feed) says *A Page post which shares a post from another Page or person may not be visible if the original post isn't visible with the access token used.*

So I presume I am missing an access permission. If so which is it? If not then how do I see posts shared to my Page?

**Edit:** I have given every possible permission to the user access token and still it does not show the shared posts. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: _Who_ shared the post onto your page? If it was a user profile - then you would need _their_ permission. And if it was another page, that you do not have admin access to - then you likely need the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app first.

Comment: @CBroe Hmm yeah if I share _my own_ post, it does appear. The idea is to have people share publicly viewable posts from around Facebook on my Page and that my app will be able to access them. As far as I can tell this should be possible with `Page Public Content Access` would that be right? I can't experiment since I need to develop an app to review first

Comment: PPCA would only work for posts shared to your page _by_ other pages, I think. If a user shares a post to your page, then your app would need permission to read their posts _from_ that particular user.

Comment: @CBroe is that from experience? PPCA docs say _Allows read-only access to public data on Pages for which you lack the manage_page login permission. Readable data includes business metadata, public comments, and posts._ this seems to imply that my app will be able to see public posts OK once reviewed - I really don't want to develop an app for review and then find it won't work when published ...

Comment: If you can‘t see a post made by another user now, on a page you _do_ have admin access to - then I doubt this will be any different with PPCA.